# mongoose equivalent to a mongoDB query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm following a [simple tutorial](https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/).

Thing is, I'm using momngoose instead of Mongo. 
I had no problems until I get to this point:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('quotes').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    // renders index.ejs
    res.render('index.ejs', {quotes: result})
  })
})
```

With this, the quotes can be accessed and manipulates on index.ejs

now, I tried doing this:

```
  app.get('/theroute', (req, res) => {
    MyMongoModel.find()
    .then(documents => {
      res.render('index.ejs', *not entirely sure on what to put here*)
    })
  });
```

but when I tried to use the documents on the index.ejs page, I got a "not defined" result.

And that's it. No sure on how to google this or what should I do.

Thanks!

Comment: You likely need to pass what you're trying to find into the `find()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
MyMongoModel.find({}, (err, foundQuotes) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    res.render('index.ejs', {quotes: foundQuotes});
}
```

The first argument passed into `find()`, the `{}`, will retrieve all database entries matching the particular model, and passes that collection into the callback function (`find()`'s second argument), as `foundQuotes`.

In the callback function, `index.ejs` is rendered (if there are no errors) and `foundQuotes` is assigned to a variable called `quotes`. `quotes` will then be accessible in your `index.ejs` file.